# ROW_NUMBER() in Redshift to select biggest row from each group?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to select one row from each group based on `COUNT(1)` field.

In other databases I'd use ROW_NUMBER() function, which in redshift is [unsupported yet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html).

Comment: Redshift now supports [ROW_NUMBER Window Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to use a `SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY group_field ORDER BY order field ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` construct like that:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       cnt
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          name,
          count(*) cnt,
          sum(1) over (partition BY id ORDER BY cnt DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS row_number
   FROM table
   GROUP BY id,
            name)
WHERE row_number = 1
ORDER BY name
```